Does there exist a Dual Network Simplex Method?
The Dual Simplex Method solves a primal infeasible (or dual feasible) basis to optimality by removing infeasible rows. What I'm interested in is if there exists something akin to the Dual Method for the Network Simplex Method, and whether it operates similarly to the Dual Simplex Method in that it solves a primal network infeasible basis by removing infeasible arcs out of the basis for feasible arcs in the same algorithmic fashion. I tried looking this problem up on both Google and Google Scholar and got little information aside from this one article in which I cannot access

What information did you got?

This, which I cannot access: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01580615. It was the only paper I found that talked about it too
